# Spring JAXB2 unmarshalling duplicate xml root element name

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb2

I have a problem un-marshalling simalar xml (same root element but different fields) to different objects with Spring3 and Jaxb2

I am using spring to define my xml converters as follows:

```
<bean id="xmlConverter"     class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
<property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"></property>
<property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"></property>
<property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
<value>com.my.project.Object1</value>
<value>com.my.project.Object2</value>
<value>com.my.project.Object3</value>
            </list>
        </property>
```

So the problem comes down to each of the objects have the same @XmlRootElement(name = "xml") but completely different fields.
When i have only one object defined each object unmarshalls correctly, but when i add more than one, it keeps assuming the last one, some overriding issue i am guessing.

Anyone have an idea of how to get around this issue?

EDIT: **Solution** I created one Larger object with all fields, this solves the problem. Not the best solution but it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different namespace for each object. For example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "xml", namespace="com.my.project.obj1")
@XmlRootElement(name = "xml", namespace="com.my.project.obj2")
@XmlRootElement(name = "xml", namespace="com.my.project.obj3")
```

Using namespace, the marshaller can differentiate between the different objects.

Comment: Hi, that does make sense.. it now picks up the right Object to marshall, but getting this: (so the xml name is "TransferTo")
getting "HttpMessageNotReadableException: 

Could not read [class com...xml.PingResponse]; 
nested exception is ...javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"TransferTo"). 
Expected elements are <{com..xml.checkwalletresponse}TransferTo>,
<{com..xml.msisdninforesponse}TransferTo>,
<{com..xml.pingresponse}TransferTo>"
any ideas?

Comment: Next time try to edit your question or ask a new one, please.
Maybe http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html helps to resolve your issue.